# Error when I try to activate phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have downloaded/ins talled phpmyadmin numerous times now and every time I try to activate it I always get this pink colored screen that points to errors in my mysql config. file controlling my username and password. Can someone please  help me with this?

Comment: What's the error shown

Answer (score 0):

Look for `config.inc.php` in `phpMyAdmin` folder.

Open it in a text editor.

Find and edit the line so it says :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

This way `phpmyadmin` will ask for your username and password